# Cannot open include file with Qt: "No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, qt-creator

I'm new to C++ and programming, and trying to work on a little project, using Qt/Qt Creator .

I was using the MinGW compiler, but especially for this project I will need to use the MSVC compiler (since I need QtWebEngineWidgets).

I have Qt 5.8 and I'm using Qt Creator. I downloaded Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (Community), and also installed wdk and winsdk 2015 (1703 version) from Microsft's website, and configured my kit. It took a while!

Unfortunately, i have an error when I try to run my program: looks impossible to include QtWidgets or QtWebEngineWidgets.

When I changed the kit of my project (from MinGW to MSVC 2015), I tried to run it but I had another error:

[Error from the original project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJAKU.png)

I wanted to avoid it by creating a new Qt empty project, and I just copied/pasted the source code. Now it looks a bit better, but as you can see I can't include QtWebEngineWidgets and QtWidgets.

[Here is the C1083 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT3mw.png)

[This is what the compiler says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ07A.png)

Note: After I added `#include <QApplication> and #include <QPushButton>` in the main, and he's doing the same thing with QApplication but don't say anything about QPushButton.

Any idea about what happend?

Thank you very much

Comment: You need to find the setting for 'additional include dirs'. I'm not sure where it is, check project properties.

Comment: You question is useless for future seekers because you use images or what is worse references to images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on project on visual studio -> click properties (on the bottom) -> go to C/C++ -> all options -> find additional include directories and there add path to your QT include folder.

Comment: I'm not using Visual Studio at all, only installed it to get MSVC 2015 and debuggers. 

However, I found how to add libraries on the project, thanks a lot!

I chose to add an external library, and QtCreator is now asking where are the include directory and lib file.

I guess that the include directory is in C:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include

But in C:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\lib there is like hundred lib files and I don't see which one to chose. 

I saw a video tutorial but it seems to be different.

Also don't know if I should check the dynamic or static case, about the links edition!